# How do I compare two members of an array of structures?

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I have a doubt about comparing two members of an array of structures.
I have my function which receives the indices of two different structures and compares them.
Finally, after all fields have been checked, the function must return an integer indicating similarity.

I made this code:

```
int compareRecord(RecordSoggetto soggetto1, RecordSoggetto soggetto2) {
    int similiarity = 0;
    if (strcmp(soggetto1.name, soggetto2.name) == 0)
        similiarity += 7;
    if (strcmp(soggetto1.surname, soggetto2.surname) == 0)
        return similiarity += 7;
}
```

I call the function in this way:

```
printf("\nInsert first index");
scanf("%d", &first);
printf("\nInsert second index");
scanf("%d", &second);
similiarity = confrontaRecord(???);
printf("\nSimiliarity= %d%%", similiarity);
```

But now I don't know what parameters I have to enter when I call the function, also I'm not sure if the parameters inside the function itself are correct
This is the structure:

```
 typedef struct {
     char name[DIM_NOME];
     char surname[DIM_COGNOME];
 } RecordSoggetto;

 RecordSoggetto soggetto[DIM_RECORD];
```

Can you help me?

Comment: It seems that you want `similiarity = confrontaRecord(sogetto[first], sogetto[second]);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri It says: Use of undeclared identifier 'soggetto'

Comment: That's why you need to provide a compilable code, you define `sogetto` in  `RecordSoggetto soggetto[DIM_RECORD];`

Comment: RecordSoggetto soggetto[DIM_RECORD]; is in main.c my function (confrontaRecord) is in function.c could this be the problem?

Comment: of course, this is the problem, if the array is in another translation unit, `main.c` doesn't have access to that array

Comment: @DavidRanieri Can I get around the error somehow or have to transfer "SubjectRecord [DIM_RECORD];" where do i have the function?
Unfortunately I can't have functions in main.
If you want I can send you the code so you know what I mean

Comment: Just declare `extern RecordSoggetto soggetto[DIM_RECORD];` inside `main` and you are done, but notice that global objects are bad practice, try to share the data with `static` objects whenever is possible.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I thought it was working, then I realized that I wrote Subject RecordSubject [DIM_RECORD]; in the struct.h file

Answer (score 2):

Your compare function has undefined behaviour. It does not return a value in every path. Change it like this:

```
int compareRecord(RecordSoggetto soggetto1, RecordSoggetto soggetto2){
  int similiarity=0;
  if (strcmp(soggetto1.name, soggetto2.name) == 0)
    similiarity+=7;
  if (strcmp(soggetto1.surname, soggetto2.surname) == 0)
    similiarity+=7;
  return similiarity;
}
```

Regarding the call:

```
similiarity = confrontaRecord(soggetto[first], soggetto[second]);
```

If you don't want to copy the full structs, you can also only pass their address, which results in better performance (less memory being copied). Please note that in this case I added `const` so that `compareRecord` can't modify the `RecordSoggetto`s. That helps prevent bugs.

```
int compareRecord(const RecordSoggetto* soggetto1, const RecordSoggetto* soggetto2){
  int similiarity=0;
  if (strcmp(soggetto1->name, soggetto2->name) == 0)
    similiarity+=7;
  if (strcmp(soggetto1->surname, soggetto2->surname) == 0)
    similiarity+=7;
  return similiarity;
}

similiarity = confrontaRecord(&soggetto[first], &soggetto[second]);
```

Comment: The problem is that I declared "Subject Record [DIM_RECORD];" in main.c, while the function was declared in structure.c I was advised to use "extern", so the program works, but I don't know if it's ok. My project is split into several files (.c / .h) and unfortunately I can't have functions in main. I don't know how I should have structured the code to be able to make it work without using extern :( If you want I can send you the code so you know what I mean

Comment: @Zeld That is a new problem that you did not mention in your question. How shall we write a good answer if you come up with other problems only after we write an answer? Regarding the declaration write a `main.h` with `extern RecordSoggetto soggetto[DIM_RECORD];` in it (and the `DIM_RECORD` macro) , then #include this file in main.c and other files where you need `soggetto`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this – you'll want to pass the records by reference instead of copying them in, as a bare struct as an argument would do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char name[32];
  char surname[32];
} RecordSoggetto;

int compareRecord(const RecordSoggetto *soggetto1, const RecordSoggetto *soggetto2) {
  int similiarity = 0;
  if (strcmp(soggetto1->name, soggetto2->name) == 0)
    similiarity += 7;
  if (strcmp(soggetto1->surname, soggetto2->surname) == 0)
    similiarity += 7;
  return similiarity;
}

// Statically allocated for example's sake
RecordSoggetto soggetto[] = {
    {.name = "asd", .surname = "dasd"}, {.name = "asd", .surname = "desd"},
};

int main() {
  int first = 0;  // would be prompted from user
  int second = 1;  // would be prompted from user
  int similiarity = compareRecord(&soggetto[first], &soggetto[second]);
  printf("Similiarity= %d%%", similiarity);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I declared "Subject Record [DIM_RECORD];" in main.c, while the function was declared in structure.c
I was advised to use "extern", so the program works, but I don't know if it's ok.
My project is split into several files (.c / .h) and unfortunately I can't have functions in main. I don't know how I should have structured the code to be able to make it work without using extern :( If you want I can send you the code so you know what I mean